# Retrieving relationships for a single node is slow

Tags: neo4j

I'm getting started with Neo4J 2.0.1 and I'm already running into performance problems that make me think that my approach is wrong. I have a single node type so far (all with the label NeoPerson) and one type of relationship (all with the label NeoWeight). In my test setup, there are about 100,000 nodes and each node has between 0 and 300 relationships to other nodes. There is a Neo4j2.0-style index on NeoPerson's only field, called profile_id (eg CREATE INDEX ON :NeoPerson(profile_id)). Looking up a NeoPerson by profile_id is reasonably fast:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:NeoPerson {profile_id:38}) return n;
+----------------------------+
| n                          |
+----------------------------+
| Node[23840]{profile_id:38} |
+----------------------------+
1 row
45 ms
```

However, once I throw relationships into the mix, it gets quite slow.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:NeoPerson {profile_id:38})-[e:NeoWeight]->() return n, e;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                          | e                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[23840]{profile_id:38} | :NeoWeight[8178324]{value:384}               |
| Node[23840]{profile_id:38} | :NeoWeight[8022460]{value:502}               |
...
| Node[23840]{profile_id:38} | :NeoWeight[54914]{}                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
244 rows
2409 ms
```

My understanding was that traversing relationships from a single node should be quite efficient (isn't that the point of using a graph database?), so why is it taking over 2 seconds for such a simple query on a small data set? I didn't see a way to add an index on a relationship whose keys are the source and/or destination nodes.

Comment: Was this the first run of the query or a subsequent run? The first run has to load the data from disk. And might be slower.

Comment: Usually you see a factor 10-20 improvement after the first run, if you don't please share some more details about your database and config with us.

Comment: Yes, running the same query twice in a row is significantly faster (585ms instead of 2409ms). But 2.4 seconds for such a simple query on a small dataset, even though it's cold? I can't believe people are using Neo4j in production if that's the best it can do. What am I missing?

Comment: From the description, this does not seem to be a "small data set". There are 100K nodes and up to 30 million relationships. You may need to tune your neo4j configuration. For the documentation on how to do that, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/embedded-configuration.html.

Comment: @cybersam That link is dead.

Comment: Here is a live link (at least right now): http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html.

Answer (score 0):

People use Neo4j in production without issues. If they have the requirement that the first user query has to return in a few ms, they warm up the caches after server start. E.g. by running their most important use-case queries upfront.

It takes some time to load the nodes and rels from disk. Esp. if the relationships (and their properties) of the single node are distributed across the relationship store file and are loaded from a spinning disk.

For the first query it also takes a bit longer as its query plan has to be built and compiled. 
That's why in production you usually use parameters to allow query caching.

What is the use-case you're trying to address?

Comment: Nodes represent people, and there are connections between many of the people. It's an app, and when people visit, their node and some of their relationship nodes will be retrieved, so it's not entirely predictable which ones will be needed ahead of time. Writes (especially relationships between nodes) are common. I was planning a much larger graph in production.

So are you saying that unless everything I need to access is precached in memory, I should expect multi-second query performance for basic queries? Of course I understand that it will be faster if cached, but that latency is awful.